# What conditions would allow for a medieval England type population to have only red or blond hair?

Tags: population, hair

Only fair haired, with no occurrences of black or brown hair.  I am seeking a reason that this type of genetic occurrence is plausible?

Comment: Welcome! Please take a moment to review the [tour] and [help] and find out [what WB.SE is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about) before you ask questions. This is question has no obvious worldbuilding context. Please edit your question giving relevant background and expectations. Otherwise, the only viable answer is "genetics".

Comment: Great, is that type of genetics plausible?

Comment: Go ahead and actually ask a question. You'll almost certainly get a good answer!

Comment: Gingers only! Love the idea. Did you know that the same gene that makes ginger Humans also makes ginger cats? And ginger cats are the greatest! Except that it is recessive. https://www.livescience.com/26633-redhead-dna-gene.html

Comment: The only real answer is to make them bleach their hair. You don't even have to force it, Norse people used to wash themselves with water and ash because they didn't have soap. Ash is alkaline which means it burns the skin and it burns the melanin inside hairs.  Melanin is a red pigment that works just like the ink inside school pens.  It becomes darker in higher density. Black is high in melanin, red is slightly lower, blond is really low in melanin and white is without any melanin in it.

Comment: If your English men don't have soap then only those who refuse to wash themselves will have black hair, the remaining population will have a mix of red-orange-white and yellow hair... Roots of the hair will be of different color and the tip of the hair will always be a lighter shade so you can have someone with hair going from red to white on its length. So one single hair could have many different colors. No need to bring the nazy or  change human genes

Comment: A true *"medieval England type population"* is a mixture of people with Pictish, Celtic, Roman (of many many kinds, from Iberia to Italy to Greece to Africa to Thrace to the Near East) and Germanic (of several kinds, continental and Scandinavian) ancestry. *England was never genetically pure*, at least not in the last four millennia. You *will* have multiple different colors of hair, colors of eyes, skin pigmentation, body types and so on.

Comment: I thought it was obvious but probably it is not since not everyone has experience with hair and a lot of people live their entire lifes never changing color of their hair. But the more you wash your hair with alkaline substances the more color it loses,  that's why the roots will always be darker and that's why not everyone will have white hair but there will be a good mix of red to white spectrum of colors. If you only wash hair once for 5 minutes it can go from pitch black to dark brown.... But nobody washes their hair only in their life, not even vikings.

Comment: There is a problem with your edit: it invalidates one of the posted answer, and that's something we don't allow.

Comment: @Mike  If this is a fictional fantasy land, no problem. It could be an uninhabited island at first that is settled by a population that is totally blond or red haired from a neighboring land.  And all the neighboring lands have only blonde or red haired people in them, so all the other groups that invade and settle the island have blonde and/or red haired people.  And if darker hair is considered bad, all dark haired kids who might be born could be killed, sold as slaves in foreign lands, castrated, made clergy who are forbidden to marry, or otherwise prevented from having children.

Answer (score 4):

If this population preferred red and blonde hair then they could only allow children to live if they had either colored hair. By only allowing these children to live, these children would also be the only ones to be able to breed and therefore they would have reduced the odds of other hair colors popping up, see: https://genetics.thetech.org/ask-a-geneticist/chances-red-haired-children.

Comment: You don't even need to go that far. Simply having people only accept to have children with those who have red or blonde hair is enough to essentially erase the other colors over generations.

Answer (score 1):

Same as today.  **They color it.**

[image: boxwod blonde]

> Blonde hair
>
> “In order that the hair might be made blonde, cook greater celandine
>   and root of agrimony and shaving of boxwood, and tie on oat straw.
>   Then take ashes of oat or vine and make a cleanser, and wash the
>   head.”

https://www.medievalists.net/2014/11/medieval-beauty-tips/

I suspect that also as today, persons starting with darker hair will arrive at a reddish hue, while people with naturally lighter hair will become blondes.

I am not sure why this would be important to these people, or to the story, but maybe the same reason for both?

Comment: [Apparently](http://exploringcelticciv.web.unc.edu/diodorus-siculus-library-of-history/) lime (the mineral) will also work, and was historically used by some Gallic peoples.

Comment: But they don't have the ginger PERSONALITY!!!! Totally fake gingers. Like artificial sweeteners - they just aren't the original taste.